# What does the raspberry pi "Run..." thing do?

Tags: pi-3, pi-3b+

I bought a raspberry pi a few months ago and i'm curious what the "Run..." thingy does.(see image)
I was able, to write in some commands but i'm not sure, what it does with it...
Can someone please give me a short explanation or a link? I searched the internet now for a few days but was not able to find an answer.

[image]

thank you!

Comment: *Using this we can interactively search through our command history for a specific command. To start we press CTRL + R together and then start typing part of the command. For example we have just used the history | grep “apt” command so we can now press CTRL + R and start typing history and the search will find that command.* https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/raspberry-pi-command-line-commands,6159.html

Comment: if you know Microsoft Windows, think `Window+R` key combo - or right click Start, Run

Comment: Ah, I am a Windows guy, have been running the "Run" command for ages, starting from Win 3.1/95/XT/ .. Win7/10. But for Rpi, since Rpi1, I need to clumsily switch to "terminal", type the often forgotten or wrongly spelled command. I felt losing face when explaining to my bad ex Win friends that Rpi did not have any GUi "Run" command, nor any so powerful shell like Win Power Shell (Bash does lose my face, so is ugly Nano).  I do have a long wish list to cover up. Happily Rpi4  is catching up and shortening the list of sorrows.  (Thks for reading my everyday use of English assignment, cheers).

Comment: Just curious, is this a menu equivalent of the Linux `Alt + F2`? Ah, yes, [it is](https://raspberryinsider.com/top-15-raspberry-pi-keyboard-shortcuts/). So, if you prefer hotkeys, just press `Alt+F2`; if you prefer the mouse, that menu does the same thing

Comment: It looks like your Pi 3 is running Raspbian Stretch. Stretch is outdated and not maintained. It's a good idea to upgrade to [Raspbian Buster](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/).

Comment: @era Try fish ;) https://fishshell.com/ *"Finally, a command
line shell for the 90s"* is a joke, the first release was 2005.

Answer (score 6):

The Run button allows you to enter Commands (ie mounting or unmounting drives - sudo mount -a or sudo umount /path/) instead of opening the command terminal.

Like this...

[image: Run Box]

---

[image: Result]